# Win + P does not show Display Changing Window

Tags: windows

I have sony vaio laptop and windows 7 is installed.
As you know if you press win + P you should see a window choosing a display.
But it is not working on my laptop, I even changed my windows too.

What should I do and where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please install the right grafic driver.

you can check witch version you have on the windows search or windows + R 
and type in dxdiag select enter. go to the tab display and look which graficcard driver you have

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: This is the Right Answer. The problem is the Graphic Driver and it needs to be installed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I suppouse your windows key is working well (Try if other combinations are working: Win + r) .

In that case, have you installed the hotfix of windows 7 (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2581613)

You can create a shortcut with the following path %windir%\System32\DisplaySwitch.exe

Answer (score 0):

Check if this service is running:

Name: Wi-Fi Direct Services Connection Manager Service

Service name: WFDSConMgrSvc

When I started this service, button started to work for me.